# Configuration to connect an Acess Point into a pfSense Network

Tags: networking, routing, router, pfsense, access-point

At the moment I have an wired network provided by my **pfSense router**. I bought an Access point ([tl-wa801nd access point](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-12_TL-WA801ND.html)), in order to have a wireless network in my wired network. In my computer host, I am able to connect me to the new wireless network, nevertheless I am not capable to connect me to the internet. The configuration is this:

In my **pfSense Router** (in Services DHCP server):

```
Subnet: 192.168.1.0
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Available Range: 192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254
Range: 192.168.1.5 - 192.168.1.254
DNS servers: 208.67.222.222, 208.67.220.220
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
```

and the other options have default values.

In my tp-link Access Point:

```
(LAN)
Type: Static IP
IP Adress: 192.168.1.4
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Gateway: 192.168.1.1
Allow remote access: no

(DHCP Settings)
DHCP Server: Disable
Start IP Address: 192.168.1.5
End IP Address: 192.168.1.254
Address Lease Time: 1 Minute
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
Default Domain: 
Primary DNS: 208.67.222.222
Secondary DNS: 208.67.220.220
```

I think this has to be with **pfSense**, since when I connect the AP into another home router, I am able to access internet. I am not sure how the configuration should be and why, maybe both Router and Access Point must have same values, but I don't know. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable the DHCP server on the TP-link box.

Most likely your wireless clients are getting DHCP off your AP and you haven't configured a correct gateway and DNS.

Comment: but if I disable DHCP server on the TP-link box, now I am not even capable to connect me to the wireless network. How do I configure correctly the gateway and DNS?

Comment: You should not need DHCP on the AP, the pfSense box will provide that. Two DHCP servers on the same LAN is mot a good idea. Also your AP has its IP inside the DHCP range of the pfSensw box. Maybe this is causing an IP conflict?

Comment: yes, I thought that, but now I don't have access to the wireless network, and I don't see why, my other computers in the pfSense network work correctly

Comment: Try setting the IP on your AP to be something outside the DHCP range.

Comment: I changed it for `192.168.1.10`, and still not capable to connect me to the wireless network

Answer (score 0):

In addition to everything else Per has said. You're AP gateway is pointed at itself. It needs to be pointed at the router.

Comment: I have already changed that, and still I can't connect me to the wireless network

Comment: Can you update your post with the your updated settings?

Comment: I've just updated my settings, maybe I have to change another thing in my pfSense Router